# I am trying to run tests on 'CalFuzzer' but it keep showing me following error

Tags: ant

Command: `ant –f run.xml deadlockfuzzer`

> BUILD FAILED Target `"–f"` does not exist in the project
>   `"calfuzzer".`

Answer (score 0):

Try typing your command manually. There is an error in your `copy and paste` approach. In the copy and paste command it's not a simple dash `-` which is `0x2D` it's the unicode character `U+2013`.